# Trying to wrap my head around python functions

Tags: python, function, parameters, return, arguments

I'm trying to print:

```
gibberish1
2
```

by using multiple functions.

I'm not sure in what way the functions should be called, what arguments said call(s) would require or the parameters I need for the functions in the scenario below.

__

How do I go about utilizing both functions in the following case?

```
def function_one():
    variable_one = 1
    variable_two = 2
    return variable_one, variable_two


def function_two():
    use_function_one_variable = 'gibberish' + str(variable_one)
    print(use_function_one_variable)
    print(variable_two)
```

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code snippet:

```
def function_one():
    variable_one = 1
    variable_two = 2
    return variable_one, variable_two


def function_two():
    variable_one, variable_two = function_one()
    use_function_one_variable = 'gibberish' + str(variable_one)
    print(use_function_one_variable)
    print(variable_two)

function_two()
```

produces your desired output:

```
gibberish1
2
```

Comment: You can check by `print(type(function_one()))` that `function_one()` returns a `tuple`. Hence you can access any of its return values by indexing: e.g. the `variable_one` return value is accessed with `function_one()[0]`, while the `variable_two` return value is accessed with `function_one()[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

From `function_two()`, you have to call `function_one()`:

```
def function_two():
    v1, v2 = function_one()
    use_function_one_variable = 'gibberish' + str(v1)
    print(use_function_one_variable)
    print(v2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_one():
    variable_one = 1
    variable_two = 2
    return variable_one, variable_two


def function_two():
    print_this_one, print_this_two = function_one()
    print_this_one += 'gibberish'
    print_this_two += 'more gibberish'
    print(print_this_one)
    print(print_this_two)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

If you want a function that prints just `gibberish1`, then you can do the following:

```
def gib():
    print('gibberish1')
```

Then if you type `gib()` it'll print what you're looking for.

If you want a function that prints a 2, you do basically the same:

```
def two():
    print(2)
```

If you want a function that concatenates both you need your number to be a string.

```
def gib2():
var1='gibberish1'
var2='2'
    print(var1+var2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Each function has it's own local scope, so generally speaking, variables defined in that function can only be accessed from within it.  One way around this is to pass the variables out of the function using return, which you're doing here.

In your code, when you call function one, it will return a tuple with variable_one and variable_two.  To access those from function_two, you can call function_one from within it like so:

```
 def function_two():
    variable_one, variable_two = function_one()
    use_function_one_variable = 'gibberish' + variable_one
    print(use_function_one_variable)
    print(variable_two)
```